# Homeassistant React component kit card breaks when moving/adding cards in React-dnd Grid. Unable to manipulate CSS and Props not helping.. any advice?

Tags: css, typescript, react-hooks, react-dnd, react-grid-layout

Ii am using the ha-component-kit for a React dashboard in Home Assistant. I am trying to make the cards be displayed and draggable using react-dnd and react-grid-layout. Once the cards are put into the containers to be draggable, they are displayed weirdly. I have tried modifying the CSS values for the cards and containers themselves but have had no luck. The following screenshot is how the cards should look, and the second screenshot is what happens when they are put into a dnd container. Advice???
[regular cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmAa6.png)

[dnd cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4VQN.png)

ha component kit i am using: https://shannonhochkins.github.io/ha-component-kit/?path=/docs/introduction-getting-started--docs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.